# NFC Detection doesn't work using NfcManager in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc

first time posting here. Am quite new to flutter.

Currently making an app that uses NFC to allow user login, however I'm unable to show the data of the NFC/print it out so I can use it. I want to be able to print out the code on it that is '0248FCF2255E81', but I can only get the metadata and it doesn't seem to be inside that.

```
RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          bool isAvailable =
                              await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
                          // Start Session
                          if (isAvailable) {
                            NfcManager.instance.startSession(
                              onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
                                Ndef ndef1 = Ndef.from(tag);
                                if (ndef1 == null) {
                                  print('Tag is not compatible with NDEF');
                                  return;
                                } else {
                                  print(await ndef1.read());
                                }
                              },
                            );
                          } else {
                            print("NFC Manager is not available");
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Open NFC Manager'),
                        color: Colors.green[300],
                      ),
```

When I click the button, it opens the NfcManager, and I should be able to get the data from the NFC tag. However, when I hover my phone over the NFC Tag, I get this error

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => Null))
```

I tried other packages like nfc_in_flutter, but that didn't work for me when trying to fork their project
I also tried flutter_nfc_reader, which did give me the metadata of the NFC tag, but not the data I wanted.

Same thing with nfc_manager, when I hover over the tag after the error pops up, I can see the metadata of the NFC tag as well, but not see the string I wanted to see.
[image]

Hope I can find some help here, thanks!

edit: The package I'm using is https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager

Comment: what types of NFC card/chip you are using ? Did you test on both(ios/android) platform ?

Answer (score 0):

tried nfc_in_flutter again and it worked, using

```
NDEFMessage message = await NFC.readNDEF(once: true).first;
```

print("payload: ${message.tag.id}");